# A lot functions in Django Model, way to separate it?

Tags: python, django

I got huge Django App with huge amount of sub-applications. Currently, i'm working on reworking of models in one subapp, so i got a... problem.
I have huge amount of separated ugly functions to work with model. Basicly, it is a someting like:

```
def get_some_things(...):
 def postprocess(...):
  pass
 def preprocess(...):
  pass
 preprocess(...)
 x = MyModel.objects.....get(1)
 return postprocess(x, ...)
```

And i got A LOT of functiongs like this and it's really ugly! And it's ugly used in current code(like `DatabaseAccessor.get_db().django_kitty().get_some_things(...)`). So, my idea was to make developers able to use these functions like this:

```
MyModel.get_some_things(...)
```

Or even like this:

```
MyModel.objects.get_some_things(...)
```

But! I got soo many functions so i can't write it inside model.py. So, i got few ideas:

1. Create model_mymodel.py and define my model with all functions inside it and static functions. But... I'm not sure, do i need to put it in model class?
2. Create mymodel_manager.py and create model manager for mymodel, define functions here. But... some of my "functions" should return just dicts, lists or even numbers. I wonder, is it ideologically wrong to make model manager be able to return something except the QuerySet?
3. Override `__getattr__` of the MyModel class and dynamicly load modules like `functions_common.py`, `functions_things.py` etc, store gathered functions into dictionary and call needed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your models require a lot of unique methods, having huge model definitions is the price you pay. If for some reason you do want to split the functionality to other files (or, for something actually useful, share common functionality) you could use a mixin approach:

```
#mymodel.py
class MyModelMixin:
    def django_kitty(self, ...):
        pass
    def postprocess(self, ...):
        pass
    def preprocess(self, ...):
        pass

#models.py
from mymodel import MyModelMixin

class MyModel(models.Model, MyModelMixin):
    pass
```

Regarding your own suggestions:

1 - If you want separate files per model, you could use this approach:

```
myapp/
    models/
        __init__.py
            from mymodel import MyModel
        mymodel.py
```

Beware that you would need to explicitly set the app_label for each model:

```
#mymodel.py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'myapp'
```

2 - The return value type of manager methods is irrelevant. The distinguishing point of managers and models is to separate *table* and *row* level functionality respectively.

3 - Sounds like unnecessary magic, overriding `Model.__getattr__` is a painful task.

Comment: Thank you for clearing my mind! I had the idea about mixins, but i really don't know why i've forgot about it. So, i think, i gonna make some files in the root folder of the app and just import it in models.py, i think it will be simplier. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like option 2 is the way to go.

There is nothing wrong with a [model manager method not returning a QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#methods-that-do-not-return-querysets).

Comment: Thank you! It seems, i've overlooked this note. This makes my soul feel better about using model manager in Django :D

Answer (score 0):

The guiding principle I use for model functions versus model managers is this: I use method functions on models regularly as long as the objective is to act on a single model object.  However if my use case required me to handle multiple objects of the model and meets my DRY incentive, I would use a model manager for that.